# is 0.0000 different from null in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a few values as NaN and a few as 0.0000. 
When i do

```
pd.isnull(df);
```

I see that it returns TRUE only for NaN but not for 0.0000.

In my dataset, I need to ignore all NaN and 0.0000. I can do it other ways, but I am a bit confused as to how null is defined.

So should I assume that 0.0000 can still be some infinitesimally small value?

Comment: Isn't the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) clear? *Detect missing values (NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays)* In numeric arrays `NaN` is used as NULLs, everywhere else `None` should be used (but `NaN` is still supported in that case).

Answer (score 2):

NULLs are used to signify *missing data*. In Python we normally use `None` to signal such a situation. Since *numeric* `numpy` arrays (an underlying datastructure in a dataframe) cannot hold `None` values, Pandas uses `NaN` as NULLs instead.

As such the [`pandas.isnull()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) will only detect `NaN` or `None` values.

`0.0000` is a perfectly valid numeric value, it is not *missing data*, and is not detected by that function.

In other words, NULL does *not* mean the same thing as zero. It means *there is no data here at all*.

Comment: Also DataFrame methods isna() or isnull() that are completely identical will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

0.0000 is just 0, a perfectly correct value. None/NaN is "not a number", some non computable value (such as 0/0). These are fundamentaly different concepts. Python **NaN** is not C++ **Null** (which is esseintialy 0). NaN is more like a notification, that during computation of this value, some kind of exception occured.